# problem with labstreaminglayer pull_sample()

Tags: c#

I'm using visual studio 2019 to build a listener for messages from Lab Streaming Layer. I can see that incoming messages are being seen, but I'm unable to pull the content. In the code below, 'ID' is a string containing the type of message.

The sending code looks like this:

```
StreamInfo streamInfo = new StreamInfo("Test", ID, 1, 0, channel_format_t.cf_string, "sample");
StreamOutlet streamOutlet = new StreamOutlet(streamInfo);
string[] msg = new string[1] { message };
streamOutlet.push_sample(msg);
```

The receiving code looks like this:

```
StreamInfo[] results = LSL.LSL.resolve_stream("type", ID);
StreamInlet inlet = new StreamInlet(results[0]);
results.DisposeArray();
string[] msg = new string[1];
inlet.pull_sample(msg);
```

It all works until the call to 'inlet.pull_sample(msg)'. I looked at the code in LSL.cs, and I can see that this call never returns:

```
res = dll.lsl_pull_sample_str(obj, tmp, tmp.Length, timeout, ref ec);
```

I think the lsl.dll is being recognized because the message is being sent. I'm stumped...any advice?

Thanks.
Don